# Simple XSLT nested IF statement

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, ibm-datapower

Here is a snippet of my code.  The input is now supposed to include 2 optional fields.  So I thought to create 4 if statements, as the URL has to be different if the fields exist or not.  The choose/when works, and the first IF statement works.  But the last 3 if one or both of the fields are not in the input, blows up.  The URL variable(DVURL) does not get populated at all.  I'm sure this is easy answer...i hope.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:string="http://symphony-cms.com/functions" xmlns:dpfunc="http://www.datapower.com/extensions/functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="datavalueagg" select="test1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="valueagg" select="test2"/>
        <xsl:variable name="variable1" select="Y"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($variable1 = 'Y' or $variable1 = 'N')">
                <xsl:if test="(($datavalueagg != '') and ($valueagg != ''))">
                    <xsl:variable name="DVURL" select="concat('http://server.com/$valueagg/$datavalueagg')"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="(($datavalueagg != '') and ($valueagg = ''))">
                    <xsl:variable name="DVURL" select="concat('http://server.com/$datavalueagg')"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$datavalueagg = '' and $valueagg != ''">
                    <xsl:variable name="DVURL" select="concat('http://server.com/$valueagg')"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$datavalueagg = '' and $valueagg = ''">
                    <xsl:variable name="DVURL" select="concat('http://server.com/none')"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="DVURL" select="concat('http://server.com/all')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Present an actual [mcve], not pseudocode.  In particular, some of the `select` expressions in your variable definitions are not valid XPath expressions; the details of the real expressions are relevant to the question, and the input XML may be, too.  Generally, we want to be able to reproduce your (minimal example) problem.

Comment: Is edit acceptable?

Comment: The edit improves the question, but you still do not provide an MCVE.  In particular, example input and expected output are needed; follow the link I provided for more information.  There are some distinct oddities in the XSL as it is now presented, but I am uncertain whether they are characteristic of your real XML.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for poor question, but I used slightly modified code.  Working now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:string="http://symphony-cms.com/functions" xmlns:dpfunc="http://www.datapower.com/extensions/functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="datavalueagg" select="test1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="valueagg" select="test2"/>
        <xsl:variable name="variable1" select="Y"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($variable1 = 'Y' or $variable1 = 'N')">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="(string-length($datavalueagg) != 0 and string-length($valueagg) != 0)">
                        <xsl:variable name="DVURL" select="concat('http://server.com/$valueagg/$datavalueagg')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="(string-length($datavalueagg) != 0 and string-length($valueagg) != 0)">
                        <xsl:variable name="DVURL" select="concat('http://server.com/$datavalueagg')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="(string-length($datavalueagg) != 0 and string-length($valueagg) != 0)">
                        <xsl:variable name="DVURL" select="concat('http://server.com/$valueagg')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="(string-length($datavalueagg) != 0 and string-length($valueagg) != 0)">
                        <xsl:variable name="DVURL" select="concat('http://server.com/none')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise/>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="DVURL" select="concat('http://server.com/all')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Without seeing the input and understanding what you're trying to accomplish, this is not helpful to anyone.

Comment: So it works now that you nested a `<xsl:when>` test rather than nested `<xsl:if>` ? Was this the only change you made or did you edit anything else somewhere we cannot see?

Comment: Again, without  an indication of the inputs and  outputs ,  it is  difficult to  say what works and what  doesnt.  That  said ,  the  revised  code may only show  one of the  options being  chosen based on the input,  as the "choose" clause only  ever  selects a  single "when" option.  In the previous code , multiple "if " clauses  can  run if the "if" test  results in true.   Furthermore , in both  code  extracts , the  variable: "DVURL" is only  defined with  the "if" or "when" clause,  and  is not defined outside  the main choose element . Again not sure if  that is the intended logic .